# Assign user_num2 with 5 if user_num2 is greater than 8. print "user_num2 is less than or equal to 8."

Tags: python, python-3.x

Task:
Print "user_num1 is negative." if user_num1 is less than 0. End with newline.
Assign user_num2 with 5 if user_num2 is greater than 8. Otherwise, print "user_num2 is less than or equal to 8.". End with newline.

Problem:
I've attached my code and for some reason when user_num2 = 8 it does not output the print statement as depicted in the output image. What am I doing wrong?

Attempted code:

```
user_num1 = int(input())
user_num2 = int(input())

if user_num1 < 0:    
    print('user_num1 is negative.')
elif user_num2 <= 8:
      print('user_num2 is less than or equal to 8.')
else:
     user_num2 = 5

print('user_num2 is', user_num2)
```

Comment: Please text as text, not an image of text.

Comment: What is `num_items`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: if you want to do two different "if" tests for two variables, do not use elif but a second "if" if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I understand from the text:
user_num1 and user_num2 tests are independant, so each has its own "if" statement. Otherwise the user_num2 test is not executed when user_num1 < 0.

```
user_num1 = int(input())
user_num2 = int(input())

if user_num1 < 0:    
    print('user_num1 is negative.')

if user_num2 <= 8:
    print('user_num2 is less than or equal to 8.')
else:
    user_num2 = 5

print('user_num2 is', user_num2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Each user gets its own "if" statements. Try this out:

```
user_num1 = int(input())
user_num2 = int(input())

if user_num1 < 0:
    print('user_num1 is negative.')

if user_num2 > 8:
    user_num2 = 5
else:
    print('user_num2 is less than or equal to 8.')

print('user_num2 is', user_num2)
```